# Calling the 'Live' option for a profile plot in Fiji with Python

Tags: python, imagej

Just a quick question really. I am trying to right a python script in Fiji (imageJ) that will bring up the plot profile UI and initiate the 'Live' option which auto-updates the plot. I have managed to open the profile plot (see below) however automatically activating the 'Live' option is proving troublesome.

```
def profileplot(self, event):
    IJ.run("Plot Profile")
```

I have looked all over the ImageJ mailing lists and API and haven't seen a reference to it. In addition within Fiji you can usually record an action by doing *Plugins>Macros>Record* but again this reveals nothing. There is reference to an older legacy plot called Dynamic Profiler but this doesn't look as nice and I would rather not use legacy code.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [API description of "ProfilePlot"](http://javadoc.imagej.net/ImageJ1/ij/gui/ProfilePlot.html), I'd say this is not possible right now. Maybe drop a message to the ImageJ mailing list to see if Wayne's willing to implement this...